# ant build for eclipse cant resolve log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, hadoop

Hi I am trying to ant build an eclipse hadoop project but get:

```
[ivy:resolve]       :: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 {common=[default]}:
[ivy:resolve]   reactor-repo: unable to get resource for commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: res=${reactor.repo}/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${reactor.repo}/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache.commons#commons-parent;5 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   reactor-repo: unable to get resource for org/apache/commons#commons-parent;5: res=${reactor.repo}/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${reactor.repo}/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
[ivy:resolve]   several problems occurred while resolving dependency: org.apache#apache;4 {}:
[ivy:resolve]   reactor-repo: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=${reactor.repo}/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${reactor.repo}/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
[ivy:resolve]   reactor-repo: unable to get resource for org/apache#apache;4: res=${reactor.repo}/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${reactor.repo}/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar
[ivy:resolve]       :: log4j#log4j;1.2.16: several problems occurred while resolving dependency: log4j#log4j;1.2.16 {common=[master]}:
[ivy:resolve]   reactor-repo: unable to get resource for log4j#log4j;1.2.16: res=${reactor.repo}/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${reactor.repo}/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.pom
[ivy:resolve]   reactor-repo: unable to get resource for log4j#log4j;1.2.16: res=${reactor.repo}/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${reactor.repo}/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve] 
[ivy:resolve] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

TIA!!!

Comment: Did you specify a value for reactor.repo in your pom? _java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${reactor.repo}/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.pom_

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to all this stuff. Any idea where I might set that and what it should be? If I look at pom.xml in Eclipse it flags a problem with the maven plugin. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same trouble. To build eclipse hadoop plugin add:

```
reactor.repo=https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/snapshots
```

into

```
hadoop_source_pack/src/hadoop-mapreduce1-project/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/build.properties
```

Generally speaking you will needed something like this in your build.properties:

```
eclipse.home=/home/cloudera/eclipse
reactor.repo=https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/snapshots
version=2.0.0-cdh4.4.0
```

It was working for me. I got hadoop distributives from https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/CDH4+Downloadable+Tarballs

Answer (score 0):

Your `ivy` plugin cannot able to resolve the url `${reactor.repo}/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom`

Check the variable `reactor.repo` is set.